# Sporfire Prompt Multiple Selection - way to cache the data list

Tags: spotfire

I am using multiple select in Prompt for column values. With this method it takes more time to load the report. Is there a way where I can keep the prompt list values cached such that when I open the report the process is faster.

Comment: I am not sure about caching prompted values, but schedules updates works nicely with large data sets.

Comment: @ jleviaguirre : you mean to use tibco automation services? i dont have access to it and dont know whether the admin has licence for it.

Comment: I meant schedules updates if you are using webplayer.

Comment: @ jleviaguirre : can you explain in detail. Is there an option where with scheduled updates the prompt selections will be cached periodically and when i open the report there wont be any time lag. This is exactly what i want and it would be helpful if you can explain with steps and more detail.

Comment: :Not sure about the prompts. How big is the data? With prompts, I believe the first person making a selection takes the hit. Second time the same selection is done by other user, data should be cashed i hope. To avoid a real user having to take the hit, then use automation services, but it has to go through all possible prompt options that will end retrieving all the data. Why not only use schedule updates without any prompts to cache it all? Webplayer handles large amounts of data in memory nicely because it does asych requests to the server to return very small chunks of data.

Comment: With prompts, the first user will take the hit because spotfire server has to retrieve those values from server (use as here). Second time, I hope they are cashed on server without having to bother the DB again, but I am not sure about this. That's why I think is best to cash all the data if you have enough resources in your spotfire server and your analysis is consumed by webplayer.

Comment: @jleviaguirre : I get what you are suggesting but the over all data is very huge. i just want to cache the unique values in columns that are displayed in the prompt. I am trying it with 'Data Connection properties' but it is not displaying the data table in order for me to try the cache options. As you said everytime spotfire hits DB for the column values of prompt. Trying to find a way around that

Comment: what about creating infolinks that contain header information. Perhaps first hierarchy levels. Then you can create detailed infolinks and set them up to grab data on demand based on selected hierarchy. For example, let's say you have country,state,city,county,road. I would create an info link that takes all countries and states and perhaps cities if data allows. Second information link is getting on demand data passing country, state, city and bring back county and roads for selected cities.